# RabbitMQ c# client callback when TCP Backpressure activated?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I haven't found a way to determine when a publisher is hung due to tcp backpressure (flow control). For my application, hanging any thread is pretty much unacceptable. I need to be able to abort the publish operation if it doesn't happen quickly. I noticed the Pika client has a callback for this, but could find nothing in the c# client docs. Does anyone have a solution for this ? I could create a background task to do the publishing, and abort the thread after some timeout, but this seems heavy handed and thread.abort has it's own problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason RabbitMQ switched from explicit flow control to throttling via TCP back-pressure  is to support more clients (many of which could not handle asynchronous methods like `channel.flow`).  Unfortunately, the way it's done, and arguably the way it should be done, is completely transparent to publishers -- there is *no way* for a publisher to tell when it's being throttled.

If you really one hard real-time guarantees for publishing, your only choice is to implement a manual timeout.  Of course, that doesn't solve the underlying issue that RabbitMQ is overloaded, so stopping the publishing, killing the connection and opening a new one will not get you closer to publishing again.

So, you either 1) need to revise why you need such strict guarantees for publishing or 2) add more nodes to the [RabbitMQ cluster](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) (which is dead-simple and is designed to improve exactly this situation).

Comment: What I think is naïve is to think blocking the publisher (and a thread) is somehow transparent to an enterprise application. If you have some business activity (say User Logged In), and you want to publish an event to the rest of your system that this occurred, you can't reliably do that on the main application thread unless you are certain you will never exceed the throttling watermark. Adding servers is fine, but if your loads are at all spikey it's sometimes hard to predict that need. Blocking a thread can have disasterous effects on web applications scalability. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Mhm.  I see.  Unfortunately, RabbitMQ makes no hard real-time guarantees.